# Word embedding algorithms in terms of performance

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to embed roughly **60 million phrases into a vector space**, then calculate the **cosine similarity** between them. I've been using sklearn's `CountVectorizer` with a custom built tokenizer function that produces unigrams and bigrams. Turns out that to get meaningful representations, I have to allow for a tremendous number of columns, linear in the number of rows. This leads to incredibly sparse matrices and is killing performance. It wouldn't be so bad if there were only around 10,000 columns, which I think is pretty reasonable for word embeddings.

I'm thinking of trying to use Google's `word2vec` because I'm pretty sure it produces much lower dimensional and more dense embeddings. But before that, are there any other embeddings that might warrant a look at first? The key requirement would be being able to scale around 60 million phrases (rows).

I'm pretty new to the field of word embeddings so any advice would help.

I should also add that I'm already using singular value decomposition to improve performance.

Comment: You are using Spark?

Comment: @eliasah nope, using numpy with openBLAS

Comment: In order to improve performance over these kind of computing considering the number of entries, you might want to consider distributed computing systems like Spark or Flink. Word2Vec is a great algorithm but it's memory munger.

Comment: Not too worried about memory tbh, doesn't seem to be that much of an issue with countvectorizer, which produces a larger matrix than word2vec (I think). The real problem is having to take the dot product of two 60million by 60 million matrices, I'd rather avoid having to port to GPU's by reducing dimension of the embedding.

Comment: Have you tried to compute PCA?

Comment: Yes I do take the SVD of the matrix of embedded vectors, but that's after the embedding happens. Do you know of a PCA technique that happens pre embedding? Also I should point out any SVD algorithm (there are a couple) involves a lot of matrix operations, which makes them infeasible on matrices of this size.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I have suggested Spark at first. I'm sorry, I'm on my phone. I don't have access to any reference whatsoever concerning pre-embedding PCA techniques.

Comment: What I'd really like to know is if there are other embedding algorithms possibly word2vec that behave in the same way as just counting frequencies as in countVectorizer BUT produce vectors of much lower dimension. Does that make sense?

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Also setting up spark for this specific task seems like overkill, also since I'm reading this data from postgres

Comment: I'm not sure that it is an overkill with that amount of data.

Comment: I think pre-embedding PCA is just preproccessing of the text lol, since getting rid of superfluous tokens results in lower dimension later!

Comment: You could be right about that!

Comment: Removing superfluous tokens shouldn't reduce the dimension by much since you are working texts. Considering a 150000 word dictionary, removing stop words per example would benefit you with a couple of dozen. That won't help.

Comment: Otherwise, you might want to consider topics modeling with Latent Dirichlet Allocation to reduce your text vector size per phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been some work recently on dynamically assigning word2vec (skip gram) dimension using Boltzmann machines. Check out this paper:

["Infinite dimensional word embeddings" -Nalsnick, Ravi](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05392)

The basic idea is to let your training set dictate the dimensionality of your word2vec model, which is penalized by a regularization term that's related to the dimension size.

The above paper does this for words, and I'd be curious to see how well this performs with phrases.